# C# MouseEventArgs "e.Delta" not working

Tags: c#, events

Hi I have an MDI application where a child window handles a number of mouse events. Everything has worked no problem (e.Button, e.Location, etc) until I tried to get the value from e.Delta (number of mouse detents).

e.Delta always returns 0.

My events are trigger no problem, just the value of e.Delta is always zero while everything else seems valid.

I've tried the following events within my child form:

MouseClick

MouseDown

MouseMove

MouseUp

I even tried handling an some mouse events in the main parent MDI window to see if it would help, but same result... e.Delta always = 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, that property probably isn't going to be valid unless it comes to you through a MouseWheel event (which I don't see on the list up there).

Try attaching to that, and you should get the event when the wheel is turned.

Comment: Thanks man, I don't know why that event isn't listed in the properties window under events. I guess I shouldn't rely on the designer tool for everything hah.

Comment: I already tried this but I can't get control_MouseWheel to fire -- put my mouse over the control, all the other mouse events fire, but not MouseWheel -- also MSDN says that e.Delta should be valid in Mouse_Click, etc. (clearly it's not, but still).

Comment: Ahh, figured it out -- unlike other mouse events -- the MouseWheel event only fires from a Form.